# Color of line between list items is not the same

Tags: react-native

I don't know why the color of line between these items is not the same:

```
styles.item = { backgroundColor: '#dddddd',
marginBottom: 1,
borderBottomColor: 'transparent' };

<View style={{backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
        <View style={styles.item}><Text>xxxx</Text></View>
      </View>
```

[image]

Comment: The color between the items is #fff and it is the same for all of them. It is the backgroundColor of the container

Comment: @nirshabi but when i see it on app some of them dont have color #fff, look like have blur or something

Answer (score 0):

That's because probably the `styles.item` style probably has a `marginBottom` value greater than `0`. Or if not, try using `marginBottom: 0` in your `styles.item`.

Also, if you're new to this, there's a component on React-native made for lists, like [Flatlist](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) and [Sectionlist](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist).

The Flatlist component supports a custom [separator component](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#itemseparatorcomponent) to serve your needs!

Here's a example usage!

```
<FlatList
  ItemSeparatorComponent={
    Platform.OS !== 'android' &&
    (({ highlighted }) => (
      <View
        style={[
          style.separator,
          highlighted && { marginLeft: 0 }
        ]}
      />
    ))
  }
  data={[{ title: 'Title Text', key: 'item1' }]}
  renderItem={({ item, index, separators }) => (
    <TouchableHighlight
      key={item.key}
      onPress={() => this._onPress(item)}
      onShowUnderlay={separators.highlight}
      onHideUnderlay={separators.unhighlight}>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  )}
/>
```